# Is an hour and a half enough time to connect United flights from Michigan, USA to Belfast, Northern Ireland?

Tags: short-connections, united-airlines, ewr

I am flying alone and have never been at this airport. Flying in from Michigan to connect to an international flight going to Belfast, Northern Ireland.

Is an hour and a half enough time and what terminal does this United flight leave from?

Comment: I would assume you're talking about Newark.  And you can look at the departure terminal and arrival terminals based on your flight numbers

Comment: United and its subsidiary United Express are spread all over the three terminals at Newark. We need your origin airport to figure out if there is a terminal change.

Comment: @Karlson Indeed, EWR is (presently) the only city to be served from BFS in the US.

Comment: @calchas Doesn't make a difference if there is only one itinerary the bags are checked through and there is an airside shuttle.

Comment: @Karlson In that case, it'll be dead easy. :)